# How to write jquery function for previous button?

Tags: html, jquery

I have created a step form with HTML & jquery which has next and previous buttons for navigating to different steps. I have written jquery function for next buttons, but could'nt do one for previous buttons. Please help me with code.

code to trigger next button

```
 var allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

  allNextBtn.click(function () {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
        curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
        nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
        curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
        isValid = true;

    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
        if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
            isValid = false;
            $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        }
    }

    if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Please add your html and css so we can test it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach to your problem:

1. You want to create a **stepper**
2. In the stepper, you would like **to show pages of a form**
3. The stepper needs to **have controls: prev, next** (, first, last?)
4. The controls should **take form validation into account** (on the current page)
5. You want to do **DOM manipulation with jQuery**

Consider the following snippet:

```js
var currentPage = 1

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // init first page
  updatePage(0)

  jQuery(".btn.next").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // checking for last item & if page input fields are valid
    const direction = ($('.page').length > currentPage && validatePage()) ? 1 : 0
    updatePage(direction)
  })

  jQuery(".btn.prev").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // checking for fist item
    const direction = 1 < currentPage ? -1 : 0
    updatePage(direction)
  })
})

// simple validation function
function validatePage() {
  const inputValue = jQuery(`[data-page-order="${ currentPage }"]`).find('input').val()
  return inputValue !== ''
}

// simple page visibility update function
function updatePage(direction) {
  if (direction === 1 || direction === -1) {
    currentPage += direction
    $(".page.visible").fadeOut().removeClass('visible')
    $(`[data-page-order="${ currentPage }"]`).fadeIn().addClass('visible')
  } else {
    $(".page.visible").removeClass('visible')
    $(`[data-page-order="${ currentPage }"]`).addClass('visible')
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}

.pages {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pages>.page {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.pages>.page.visible {
  display: block;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="pages">
      <div class="page" data-page-order="1">
        <label for="input1">Input 1:
          <input id="input1" type="text" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="page" data-page-order="2">
        <label for="input2">Input 2:
          <input id="input2" type="text" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="page" data-page-order="3">
        <label for="input3">Input 3:
          <input id="input3" type="text" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button class="btn prev">PREV</button>
      <button class="btn next">NEXT</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

You can see that with the manipulation of a single variable (`currentPage`) `prev` & `next` steps can be done - with validation rules, form pages appear/disappear with a `fadeIn/fadeOut`and all.

I do hope that this snippet gives you the idea about how to solve a problem like this - break it down to requirements that are simple and then don't overcomplicate :) Just add one feature at a time (like prev/next, validation, etc.).